# Confusion regarding "Handling column default value when upgrading to Room 2.2.0"?

Tags: android, android-room

I'm referring to https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions.md#handle-default-values-migrations

I'm kinna confused with the guideline. My understanding is that

If you add a `NON NULL` new column

```
@Entity
public class Song {
    // ...
    @NonNull
    final String tag;
}
```

Using the following `ALTER TABLE` migration strategy is wrong

---

### Wrong

```
static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1, 2) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL(
            "ALTER TABLE Song ADD COLUMN tag TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT ''");
    }
};
```

---

You need to use the following `drop and re-create` migration strategy

### Correct

```
static final Migration MIGRATION_2_3 = new Migration(2, 3) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE new_Song (" +
                "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL," +
                "name TEXT," +
                "tag TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '')");
        database.execSQL("INSERT INTO new_Song (id, name, tag) " +
                "SELECT id, name, tag FROM Song");
        database.execSQL("DROP TABLE Song");
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE new_Song RENAME TO Song");
    }
};
```

---

That even confuse me. Isn't both methods, will end up having the same column - `tag TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT ''` ? How does the former method is marked as a problematic method?

Can someone can provide an simple example, to explain what problem might occur by using `ALTER TABLE`, and how `drop and re-create` might overcome the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: That bit of documentation is rather confusing. I filed [a request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/137515134) to hopefully have it expanded, pointing to your question here.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare, looks like I'm not the only one who confuses. I had starred your issue request.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After having discussion with the original author via 
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/137515134, here's a simple to understood example.

---

## version 1,  Room 2.1.0

```
@Entity
public class Song {
    @PrimaryKey
    final long id;
}
```

## version 2, Room 2.1.0 (Added @NonNull)

```
@Entity
public class Song {
    @PrimaryKey
    final long id;
    @NonNull
    final String tag;
}

static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1, 2) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL(
            "ALTER TABLE Song ADD COLUMN tag TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT ''");
    }
};
```

## version 3, Room 2.2.0 (Upgraded Room to 2.2.0, Added @ColumnInfo)

```
@Entity
public class Song {
    @PrimaryKey
    final long id;
    @ColumnInfo(defaultValue = "")
    @NonNull
    final String tag;
}

static final Migration MIGRATION_2_3 = new Migration(2, 3) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE new_Song (" +
                "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL," +
                "tag TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '')");
        database.execSQL("INSERT INTO new_Song (id, tag) " +
                "SELECT id, tag FROM Song");
        database.execSQL("DROP TABLE Song");
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE new_Song RENAME TO Song");
    }
};
```

## Reader Note

1. Database version 2 (who never went through MIGRATION_1_2) doesn't have DEFAULT '' in its SQLite schema. MIGRATION_2_3 is required.
2. Database version 2 (who already went through MIGRATION_1_2) has DEFAULT '' in its SQLite schema. MIGRATION_2_3 has no harm.
3. In SQLite, there is no way to ALTER an column to add DEFAULT '' constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the example refers to two schema versions (1 and 2), but different Room versions (prior to 2.2.0 and equal or greater). They key is in these sentences:

> However, versions of Room previous to 2.2.0 are unaware of such changes (*aka no @ColumnInfo*), resulting in a schema mismatch between a user of the application that had a fresh install versus a user who migrated from version 1 to 2. Specifically, a newly created database at version 2 would not contain the default value.

So what these sentences are telling us is that you have an app implemented with Room 2.1.x or lower, which has **no @ColumnInfo**, and you have **already** upgraded your schema to version 2 with `ALTER TABLE Song ADD COLUMN tag TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT`. At this point, you get a new user install, which lets Room 2.1.x create a version 2 of the schema *without* the default value (since @ColumnInfo did not exist).

Now users are upgraded to a binary of Room 2.2.0  with `@ColumnInfo`, and Room will complain about the hash of the database being different for one subset of your users. So the `MIGRATION_2_3` outlined in the document would be needed only for those users who let Room 2.1.x or before create their schema 2 version without default value. It is thus a *dummy* update for users who had migrated from version 1 to 2 through the manual `ALTER TABLE`. But it is easier to performa *nop* for some users than start adding conditional logic in your upgrade code path to try and detect when the change is actually needed.

Another way to rephrase this would be that developers using a hand written `ALTER TABLE` *with* default value for a column where upgrading their database to a schema different from the one Room would create from scratch.